# 'camelot' has no attribute 'read_pdf'

Tags: python, pdf

```
AttributeError: module 'camelot' has no attribute 'read_pdf'
```

I have installed `camelot`, `camelot-py`, `camelot-py[all]` even with tabula, tried tabula-ty. nothing worked, tried to import read_pdf from camelot, tried to use camelot.io, always get this error of no attribute 'read_pdf'

Answer (score 4):

from the docs:

https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/install.html#install

`pip install "camelot-py[cv]"`